# Change the hover annotation with coordinate name

Tags: annotations, plotly, surface

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkWoz.png) is the surface plot in concerned.
I want to change the `x,y,z` in the floating annotation (the black box) to the name of the coordinate. For example, if my x axis is named `width`, i wish the floating annotation telling like `width:0.12345`. How can i do that?

The picture is from this tutorial of plotly: https://plot.ly/python/3d-parametric-plots/

Comment: You should add your images inline rather than in links to get better answers.

Comment: You would need to add a list with your hover annotations to `text` and it should work, see https://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/RGJpoO for a JS example